# Query the database for the value of a ckeditor field

Tags: database, 9

So I want to QUERY the database for the contents of a field, the trouble is the field is a ckeditor field, so how do I write the condition correctly?

Normally it would be something like this:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
$query->condition('field_ckeditor_field', $value_to_match); (edited)
```

But for CKEditor fields there is a _value and _format column in the db too, I want to make my string to the contents of the _value column.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The `value` column should be the default if you don't specify a column. You can however query only the raw database content, not how it is formatted according to the `format` column.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't getting the expected result from the above, but upon reading your comment I investigated further and realised I made a mistake elsewhere, so this does indeed work as you might expect.